# r How to change vector values?

Tags: r

How do I change 3 values as a set in a vector, eg:

```
v=c(1,1,1,1,1,6,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,2)
r=v[which(v %in% c(6,2,3))] = c(6,0,8) 
r
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 6 0 8 4 4 4 4 4 6
```

The result comes with a warning:  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

The idea result I need is :

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 6 0 8 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

I only want the 3 values to change when they are as a set/group, not individually, any suggestion would be great appreciated!

Edit:
I'm Sorry guys, actually there are more than one set of 6,2,3 in my data, the example should be look like:

```
v=c(1,1,2,1,1,6,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,2,6,2,3,4)
```

And the result be:

```
[1] 1 1 2 1 1 6 0 8 4 4 4 4 4 2 6 0 8 4
```

Comment: On your logic, I think this works: `v[match(c(6,2,3), v)] = c(6,0,8)`

Comment: @alexis_laz - that will fail if any of `c(6,2,3)` comes individually before they come as a set.

Comment: @thelatemail: You're right; I overlooked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite different way using regular expressions:

```
as.numeric(strsplit(gsub("6 2 3", "6 2 8", paste(v, collapse = " ")), " ")[[1]])
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 6 2 8 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

This will replace all instances of `c(6, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package:

```
rollapply(v, width=3, function(x) all(x == c(6, 2, 3)))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And then you can use that boolean to replace the values you want:

```
s <- which(rollapply(v, width=3, function(x) all(x == c(6, 2, 3))))

v[s:(s+2)] <- c(6, 0, 8)
```

In one happy function:

```
rolling_replace <- function(v, p, r) {
  l <- length(r)
  s <- which(rollapply(v, width=l, function(x) all(x == p))) 
  v[s:(s+l-1)] <- r

  return (v)
}
```

Comment: I think the `match` solution will fail if any of `c(6,2,3)` comes individually before they come as a set.

Answer (score 1):

Base R function using `rle`

```
seqrepl <- function(v,find,repl) {
  l <- length(find)
  rv <- rle(v %in% find)
  start <- cumsum(rv$lengths)[which(rv$lengths==l & rv$values==TRUE)-1]+1
  v[start:(start+(l-1))] <- repl
  v
}
```

Result:

```
seqrepl(v=v,find=c(6,2,3),repl=c(6,0,8))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 6 0 8 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

An alternative using `embed`:

```
seqrepl2 <- function(v,find,repl) {
  l <- length(find)
  start <- which(colSums(t(embed(v,l)) == rev(find)) == l)
  v[start:(start+(l-1))] <- repl
  v
}

seqrepl2(v=v,find=c(6,2,3),repl=c(6,0,8))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 6 0 8 4 4 4 4 4 2
```